# PHP script ends after > (not ?>)

Tags: php

I got a really annoying error. After an > my script ends.

```
<html>
<body>
    <h1>Upload file to see previous upload!</h1>
    <form action="index.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label for="file">Filename:</label>
        <input type="file" name="file" id="file">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
    <?PHP
            if (isset ($_FILES["file"])) {
                $allowedExts = array("jpeg", "jpg", "png");
                $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
                $extension = end($temp);
                if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
                  || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
                  || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
                  || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
                  || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
                  && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 1048576)
                  && in_array($extension, $allowedExts)) {
                    if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
                        echo "Error: Couldn't upload file!";
                    } else {
                        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "files/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
                    }
                } else {
                    echo "Upload a file NAO!";
                }
            }
        ?>
</body>
</html>
```

So on my page I can read this: "`0) { echo "Error: Couldn't upload file!"; } else { move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "files/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]); } } else { echo "welcome!"; } } ?>` "

Well, guess what! That was not my intention to do... So if someone can explain me why this is happening I will be thankful.

Comment: View the source of your web page.  I bet you'll see the other part of your script's code in there.

Comment: I'm not sure if it matters, but shouldn't `<?PHP` be `<?php` (lowercase)?

Comment: Is this in a `.php` or a `.html` file?  If it's not `.php`, this won't work.

Comment: @RocketHazmat It's a .php

Comment: `PHP` vs `php` doesn't matter.  Either one will trigger the interpreter.

Comment: which doctype are you using?

Comment: Sorry guys replied on thw wrong person. So, It's a .php file and <?php doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @user2741021: Are you sure PHP is running at all?  Try just `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`.

Comment: @pdoherty926 Doctype? I never put that on the first line and it always works.

Comment: @pdoherty926: What does doctype have to do with anything?

Comment: Doctype is irrelevant.  PHP doesn't know or care about the HTML (or XML, or text, etc) in the page; it just looks for the `<?php` (or certain other sequences) to know which parts are PHP code.

Answer (score 5):

PHP is not being processed at all.  Ensure that your page is a `.php` page and on a PHP server.  Otherwise, ensure that Apache is processing PHP for whatever file extension you are using.

Also, note that it is more common to use lowercase PHP in `<?php` instead of `<?PHP`, although it appears that capitalization doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2):

Because of the wrong file name OR a `misspelled start of php code` i.e. `<?PHP` instead of `<?php` following code is being considered part of a HTML tag:

```
 <?PHP
        if (isset ($_FILES["file"])) {
            $allowedExts = array("jpeg", "jpg", "png");
            $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
            $extension = end($temp);
            if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
            || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
            || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
            || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
            || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
            && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 1048576)
            && in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
            {

            if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] >
```

Note start `<`.... end `>`

And rest is what you see in your browser `verbatim`.

Rename your file with `.php` extension.

And preferably change PHP code as:

```
<?php
// PHP code here
?>
```

**EDIT:** Thanks for all the comments, it appears `<?PHP` or `<?php` both will work.

**EDIT 2:** Another thing to check is Apache config for a line similar to this:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
```

Which basically tells Apache to treat all `.php` files as PHP scripts.

Comment: I just checked and `<?PHP ... ?>` works.  I'm a bit surprised at that.

Comment: Capitalization does not matter for the open tag.

Comment: PHP's rather lax about caps, actually.  Only variable names, array keys, and some constant names are case-sensitive.

Comment: You mean `<?php`    not `<php`!